# Сброс статической переменной в ASP.NET на Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, azure, static

Я реализовал чат на веб сокетах согласно этой статье https://habrahabr.ru/post/145077/
Запаблишил его на Azure и обнаружил проблему - когда открываю новую страницу с чатом, то иногда получаю новую статическую переменную `Clients` и тогда этот чат уже не отправляет сообщения на открытые ранее страницы, хотя они отлично работают между собой.
Получается, у разных чатов могут быть разные статические переменные `Clients` со своими списками веб сокетов.

```
// Список всех клиентов
    private static readonly List<WebSocket> Clients = new List<WebSocket>();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему? Может можно настроить, что бы новая статическая переменная не создавалась? Или можно хранить список `Clients` в другом месте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как только запускаются несколько экземпляров вашего приложения за балансировщиком, то нужно реализовать общение этих экземпляров между собой. Каждый из них естественно работает изолированно и получает свою статическую переменную Clients. Нужно организовать пересылку сообщений между экземплярами приложения.

Посмотрите в сторону [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) и как реализовать массштабирование [SignalR Scaleout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus)

Коммуникации между Azure Web Sites можно организовать только через Azure Service bus. Или другую очередь. Либо обмениваться сообщениями через базу данных. Для Azure Web Roles добавляется возможность [взаимодействовать 
между ролями](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/articles/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances/) в виртуальной сети.

Comment: Или посмотрите в сторону Interrole Communication, если ваше приложение крутиться на Azure Web Roles...

Comment: На самом деле разницы нет как реализовать, самое главное для горизонтального масштабирования нужно знать, что сообщения нужно маршрутизировать между экземплярами приложения.

Comment: В этом как раз главный вопрос - какие есть способы маршрутизировать сообщения между экземплярами приложения. И какой наиболее простой для Azure Web Sites. А еще интересен принцип их работы - только internal endpoints или есть еще варианты?

Comment: Дописал в ответ, обязательно посмотрите про SignalR Scaleout, там весь принцип изображён первым же рисунком.

Comment: Всем спасибо, очень полезная информация, но решение оказалось намного проще! manage.windowsazure.com - в разделе масштабирование почему-то стояло 2 экземпляра. Поставил 1 и все заработало.

Comment: Если у вас тестовый проект то можно ограничится 1 экземпляром, но если боевое решение, то нужно программировать взаимодействие экземпляров иначе при нагрузке вы упрётесь в ресурсы одного экземпляра.